# How do I find the index of the first occurrence of a regex starting after a certain position in the string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, position

I'm usign Ruby 2.4.  How do I get the position of a regex in my string starting after a certain position in my string?  I have learned taht I can use this

```
pos = content =~ my_regex
```

to find the position of the first occurrence of the regex, but if I want to find the position of the reg starting after, say, index 15 in the string, how do I add that into my expression above?

Comment: content[15..-1]

Comment: Yeah but think about it -- that doesn't work, right?  You are getting the position of the item in content[15..-1], not the position of the item in content.  If the item occurs at position 16 of content, content[15..-1] would return 1, which isn't what I want.  I want position 16.

Comment: use `pos = (content[offset_index..-1]=~ my_regex) + offset_index`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-index) with an offset instead of `=~` or `match`:

```
"hello".index(/[aeiou]/, 3)   #=> 4
```

Comment: That's not my question though.  How would I start searching for the regular expression after a particular position in the word "hello,", for example, position 3?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the offset. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
content.slice(index..-1) =~ your_regex
```

Comment: You would need some more logic to get the correct index, though.